# Place absolute div under relative div

Tags: html, css, angular

I don't know if is possible through CSS only to have one `absolute` `footer` under a `relative` element - being the relative one different in height due to the nature of it: either change of content or responsiveness. My HTML (using Angular 5):

```
<main>
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <div class="content-container" [@fadeAnimation]="routeTransition(outlet)">
        <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</main>
```

The reason why I want to have that is because the relative element contains the view of the user and I'm using angular animations which happen to "require" the elements that get displayed being absolute positioned in order to get the desired visualisation.

The problem with that is that for large elements I am having issues because the footer which is also absolute, does overlap the actual content if that makes sense.

I want to have a "sticky footer" at the bottom of the page so that it has absolute configuration etc (app-footer will render footer):

```
footer{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

My CSS:

```
main{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.content-container{
    position: relative;
}

/deep/ router-outlet~* {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

That was working fine till I added the `relative` to the `.content-container` to have the absolute position to the inner element.

A possible workaround I came across was to give a fixed height to the .content-container class and do the different resolutions so I can push down the footer. However I don't think that's possibly the best approach. I'm using Angular 4 if that's of any help. I also had a look at [How to position element below relative positioned element without overlapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898835/how-to-position-element-below-relative-positioned-element-without-overlapping) but again, the suggested solution was to do with hardcoding the height.

**UPDATE 1**: I have updated the question with more detailed info. Hope it is now clear.

**UPDATE 2**: Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/FHhncrGBcO9jaNRiUfJQ?p=preview

Comment: From the question its not quite clear about the output that's required on screen. Ca you elaborate why do you want to place a floating footer under relative container ?

Comment: Have I missed something (HTML6?) or this is not HTML?

Answer (score 8):

Parent:

```
position: relative;
```

Child:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
top: 100%;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem, you need to set a `position: relative` **and** a `z-index` to your `.content-container`.

Keep in mind that the `z-index` and the `absolute` positioning refers to the next relative parent. This is the body by default, but it could be a div with a `position: relative` in-between.

```css
.content-container{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  
  background-color: rgba(180,100,50,.7);
  padding: 85px 20px;
}

footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="content-container">
    content
  </div>
  
  <footer>footer</footer>
  
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What if the "content" inside content-container is a div with absolute positioning? That's the problem i'm facing right now. I'm not sure if this set up works with it (at least I've tried and I don't get the desired solution... because the footer still overlaps)

Comment: I have created this Plunker in order to try to ilustrate the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/FHhncrGBcO9jaNRiUfJQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use position:fixed for your footer.

For example:

```
footer{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

"fixed" means: relative to the view-port (and not relative to the nearest element with a position)

Comment: trouble is I want it to be placed naturally at the bottom of the page (not necessarily meaning is at the bottom of the view-port)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, use a z-index 
`footer {z-index:0;}
.content-container {z-index:1;}`

Comment: Just tried it. It doesn't work. Maybe I need to add something else?

Comment: Sorry,  I make mistake) add this styles to your:)

Comment: That didn't work I think because the inner div inside the content-container has also absolute positioning?

Comment: I think we could start with this: https://plnkr.co/edit/FHhncrGBcO9jaNRiUfJQ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Currently your looks like this:

1. content-container is a div. It has explicitly set relative position to the document, since there is no node above with position: relative
2. after content-container there is a footer with position: absolute. Since there is no node with relative position above, it is absolute to the document

Based on what you write, footer overlaps content. And this is true. Because content-container and footer are positioned to the document, so are on the same level. That means they are rendered based on the document order:

1. Content container is rendered
2. Footer is rendered

Since that said, because footer is rendered last, it will overlap content container content.

To fix it you need to make sure footer will be rendered before content, or make sure whatever order they are rendered, footer will be rendered above.

To change rendering order you can just reposition container-content in the HTML code and place it after footer div.

But this is a fragile and troublesome solution.

There is fortunately a solution to this problem. You can explicitly indicate on what layer of rendering element should be. To do this you need to use z-index CSS property.

```
footer {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

It tells browser that footer shoud be rendered above, way above other content elements.

Default value of z-index is auto. It translates to a value of 0. So if we set z-index to 1, node will be rendered above other elements on equal level without z-index being set.